# Errors downloading a video file by request python

Tags: python, request, operating-system

I am trying to download a video from the website, but I am unable to download the video specifically. I am unable to download the video. I don't see any error but I also don' see a downloaded video , i see only empty file.mb4 , this is  Movies Website

```
import requests
import os

url_link = "https://cdn1.mycima1.shop/run/4b1a92b66b4506480bd140742f0862dd20f871833addcca5c2d607c4f7a294a55a632d862996c06cc24af17a6e0ef842aaa26eeca6ffb58fd0b7233efa161f6acec834a54a39d78f42c17a2cb644f65c68fd25828eead55037e616742837729a7f5a2d?Key=kRU5HTCk04e5wKG1l91y3g&Expires=1698896857"


def download_video(url):
    local_filename = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\Music\\aflim_dwonload", "video.mp4")
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename

download_video(url_link)

print("done")
```